# Rest Template giving 400 Bad Request error

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am trying to make a REST call using Springs `RestTemplate` but I keep getting the HTTP response status 400 (bad request).

Can anyone please help on this?

```
RestTemplate transactiontemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders transactionheaders = new HttpHeaders();
transactionheaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+AccessToken);
transactionheaders.add("Accept", "application/json");
transactionheaders.add("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip");
transactionheaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(transaction));
HttpEntity<TransactionRequestDTO> transactionEntity = new                 
HttpEntity<TransactionRequestDTO> (transaction, transactionheaders);
ResponseEntity<String> transactionresponse = transactiontemplate.exchange(LocationUrl+"/"+locationId+"/transactions", 

HttpMethod.POST, transactionEntity, String.class);
//String answer = transactiontemplate.postForObject(LocationUrl+"/"+locationId+"/transactions", transactionEntity, String.class);

//System.out.println(answer);
ObjectMapper transactionmapper = new ObjectMapper();
TransactionResponseDTO transactionResponseObject = transactionmapper.readValue(transactionresponse.getBody(), TransactionResponseDTO.class);
return transactionResponseObject;
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. What is your sever side implementation? Or how does the API documentation, for the REST request your trying to do, look like? It most probably will be the server which is rejecting your request. Does the response body contain any information why it might be rejected?

Comment: Formatting and minor verbal changes

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request

Comment: `{
    "timestamp": 1508344349503,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
    "message": "400 Bad Request",
    "path": "/api/payment/charge"
}
`
When I am trying to hit square web service directly using POSTMAN it is working fine.
But when I am hitting it with my server implementation it is showing above error.

Comment: you can check below link for detailed documentation:

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox